# calling a function in a select statement in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to call a function in a select statement. It didn't work that is way I asking for help.

The following Code is like example and will be run in a Package:

THE FUNCTION:

```
Function sum_val(val1 in NUMBER, val2 in NUMBER) return float is

    u float;
BEGIN

    u := (val2+ val1) / 100;         

    return u;

END sum_val;
```

SELECT statement:

```
PROCEDURE xy_prc(pi_table_in   IN VARCHAR2) IS

BEGIN

sql_stmt := 'CREATE TABLE AS tbx
             SELECT 
            t.*, '|| sum_val(t.val1, t.val2) ||' AS Val3
            FROM '|| pi_table_in ||' t';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt; 

END;
```

The problem is here:

```
'|| sum_val(t.val1, t.val2) ||' AS Val3
```

In this case I have to declare t.val1, t.val2 and the values of them from the SELECT statement will be not replaced.

This also didn't worked:

```
'|| sum_val('t.val1', 't.val2') ||' AS Val3
```

In this case `'t.val1', 't.val2'` will be values(STRINGS)!

It that possible to call this function with SELECT statement?

Many thanks for your Answers!

Comment: Why not:  ... `'t.*, sum_val(t.val1, t.val2) AS Val3'`...  let the function be called as part of the select in the dynamic SQL? why any `||` at all?

Comment: Its does not work. ORA-00904

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me you're trying too hard :P

can't you just let the function be called at the time the dynamic query executes?

```
PROCEDURE xy_prc(pi_table_in   IN VARCHAR2) IS

BEGIN

sql_stmt := 'CREATE TABLE  tbx AS
             SELECT t.*
                  , sum_val(t.val1, t.val2) AS Val3
            FROM '|| pi_table_in ||' t';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt; 

END;
```

Comment: This is right :).. When I try to do that, I get an error: ORA-00904.

Comment: So.... does val1 and val2 exist in the variable pi_table_in defining the table?  I'm guessing not! oh... and shouldn't it be create table tbx as not create table as tbx when you're trying to create a table from a select?

Comment: Yes. Trying to call the function with real values like sum_val(333, 555) AS Val3 , also getting ORA-00904! :(

Comment: So get it to work w/o dynamic then switch it up...  should work.  `create table tbx as select t.*, sum_val(t.val1, t.val2) as val3 from tablename t`  then simply substitute tablename...  I guess I need to try it.  (I guess I'm sying before you execute immediate write out sql_stmt and debug that.

Comment: I will try it now

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you cannot define function SUM_VAL as a package function if you want to use it in SQL query.
It has to be created in the schema.

```
create or replace Function sum_val(val1 in NUMBER, val2 in NUMBER) return float is

        u float;
    BEGIN

        u := (val2+ val1) / 100;         

        return u;

    END sum_val;
```

Of course your procedure can be in package. See the corrected syntax below

```
procedure xy_prc(pi_table_in in varchar2) is
sql_stmt varchar2(1000);
BEGIN

sql_stmt := ' create table tbx as  SELECT 
            t.*, sum_val(t.val1, t.val2) as  Val3
            FROM '|| pi_table_in ||' t';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt; 

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks for your Answers!

The solution should to be acutely easy. I can call the function COUNT() from any DDL-Script, function or package. My function "sum_val()" could be only called in my Package.

As Mina said, the function has to be created as following:

```
create or replace Function...
```

to be able to called in the SQL-statment like the function COUNT() like `Select count(*) from tb` or any other function of SQL.

The Problem is, as (create or replace Function) function will be available in the schema and can be called from any package or DDL-Script. I wanted to create a private function, that can be only called from the Package.

My Solution is: the function has to be declared as a public object in the package, like this:

```
CREATE PACKAGE test AS
   PROCEDURE xy_prc(pi_table_in in varchar2);
   Function sum_val(val1 in NUMBER, val2 in NUMBER) return float;
END test;
/


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test AS

    Function sum_val(val1 in NUMBER, val2 in NUMBER) return float is

        u float;
    BEGIN

        u := (val2+ val1) / 100;         

        return u;

    END sum_val;

   procedure xy_prc(pi_table_in in varchar2) is
      sql_stmt varchar2(1000);
   BEGIN

      sql_stmt := ' create table tbx as  SELECT 
               t.*, test.sum_val(t.val1, t.val2) as  Val3
               FROM '|| pi_table_in ||' t';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt; 

   END xy_prc;

END test;
/
```

with this way I can call the function `test.sum_val(t.val1, t.val2)` in any SQL-Statment inside the package.